# matlab how to call a class method that changes prop from another class method

Tags: matlab, class, methods

If I call a method (receiving and returning `obj`) it changes my property.

But if I call that method from another method it fails. I tried all kinds of ways but still failing.

```
 classdef AClass
  properties
    A;
  end
  methods 
    function obj = ChangeA(obj, v)
      obj.A = v;
    end
    function obj = CallChangeA(obj)
      obj.ChangeA(4);
      %obj = obj.ChangeA(4);
      %ChangeA(obj, 4);
      %obj = ChangeA(obj, 4);
      % none of these works
    end
  end
end

% ------ script: 
a1 = AClass;
a1.A = 1;
a1.ChangeA(2); % a1.A = 2

a2 = AClass;
a2.A = 3;
a2.CallChangeA(); % a2.A = 3 !!!  not four
```

How do I write the code so calling from 1 method to the other updates the property?

Comment: Your sample code does not function. `ChangeA` has `a` as an input, but tries to set `obj.A` with `mz`, which is not defined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Other than the obvious typos in your example code, as I commented above, I would highly suggest taking a look at the [difference between MATLAB's Handle and Value classes](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/comparing-handle-and-value-classes.html). By default, MATLAB classes are value classes, so each time the object is passed to a function an independent copy is created. If you're making changes to this object then you need to return it as an output:

```
classdef AClass
    properties
        A;
    end
    methods
        function obj = ChangeA(obj, a)
            obj.A = a;
        end

        function obj = CallChangeA(obj)
            obj = obj.ChangeA(4);
        end
    end
end
```

Which functions as expected:

```
>> a1 = AClass;
>> a1.A = 1

a1 = 

  AClass with properties:

    A: 1

>> a1 = a1.CallChangeA()

a1 = 

  AClass with properties:

    A: 4
```

Handle classes, on the other hand, are references to a single underlying object, allowing for (among other things) in place modification of the object:

```
classdef AClass < handle
    properties
        A;
    end
    methods
        function ChangeA(obj, a)
            obj.A = a;
        end

        function CallChangeA(obj)
            obj.ChangeA(4);
        end
    end
end
```

Which also functions as expected:

```
>> a1 = AClass;
>> a1.A = 1;
>> a1.A

ans =

     1

>> a1.CallChangeA()
>> a1.A

ans =

     4
```

Comment: So the first remarked option was correct, but also I need to call the function into a copy of the object.  

    `a1 = a1.CallChangeA(4);`

Otherwise `a1.CallChangeA(4);` creates a copy of the AClass and does not store the results in a1.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. I've provided both options: one that modifies a copy of `a1` and one that modifies `a1` directly.

Comment: I'm saying thank you!!  and understanding your answer. Not asking further. 

Just pointing out from your very detailed full answer what I have to modify in my code, to get it working. The original code had a line with the remark that it doesn't work. It would have worked if the call to the function in the first place would copy the result into the object. Thank you again!!!